# How to Select Clicked Link Class or ID After AJAX Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Like button. When the button is clicked one record is inserted into the DB via Ajax. If the insert is successful I change the name of the button to Unlike.
In the page I have 10+ like button and I want to select the clicked button.
I'm trying Using `$(this)` but that's not working for this specific code.
Here is the code.

```
$('.content').on('click', '.like_music', function(){
    var music_id = $(this).parents('.music-item').attr('id');
    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
        url:'add_like_music.php',
        data:{'music_id':music_id},
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
            if (data == "YES"){
                $(this).html('unlike')
            }
        }
    })
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use context option of ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
   context: this,
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` is accessible inside the function itself, but not in the callback. You could store it in a variable outside the ajax call:

```
$('.content').on('click','.like_music',function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var music_id = $this.parents('.music-item').attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'add_like_music.php',
        data:{'music_id':music_id},
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
            if(data=="YES"){
                $this.html('unlike');
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
$('.content').on('click','.like_music',function(){
var music_id = $(this).closest('.music-item').attr('id');
                         ^-----i change this
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'add_like_music.php',
    data:{'music_id':music_id},
    success:function(data){
        alert(data);
        if(data=="YES"){
            $this.html('unlike');
        }
    }
});
```